# Julia - console behaving differently than include("myfile.jl")

Tags: julia

I would like to execute the following code, which works perfectly well when I type every line into my Julia console on Windows 10, but throws an error because of the mismatching type `LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}` (my subsequent code expects `Array{Float64,2}`).

This is the code:

```
x = [0.2, 0.1, 0.2]
y = [-0.5 0.0 0.5]

fx = x * y
fy = fx'

return fx::Array{Float64,2}, fy::Array{Float64,2}
```

There is a TypeError, because `fy` seems to be of type `LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}` instead of `Array{Float64,2}`.

How can I do a transpose and get a "normal" Array{Float64,2} object ?

And why does this work when I type every line into my Julia console, but does not when I run the file via include("myfile.jl") ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `collect` to have a copy of actual data rather than a transformed view of the original (note that this rule applies to many other similar situations):

```
julia> x = [0.2, 0.1, 0.2];                         
julia> y = [-0.5 0.0 0.5];

julia> fx = x * y                                     
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:                                 
 -0.1   0.0  0.1                                      
 -0.05  0.0  0.05                                     
 -0.1   0.0  0.1                                      

julia> fy = fx'                                       
3×3 LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}:  
 -0.1  -0.05  -0.1                                    
  0.0   0.0    0.0                                    
  0.1   0.05   0.1                                    

julia> fy = collect(fx')                              
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:                                 
 -0.1  -0.05  -0.1                                    
  0.0   0.0    0.0                                    
  0.1   0.05   0.1
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but one should make sure that `fx'` really gives them what they expected and if materializing `fx'` is really needed as I have outlined in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for! :-)

Answer (score 2):

To get a normal `Matrix{Float64}` use:

```
fy = permutedims(fx)
```

or

```
fy = Matrix(fx')
```

Those two are not 100% equivalent in general as `fx'` is a recursive adjoint operation (conjugate transpose), while `permutedims` is a non-recursive transpose, but in your case they will give the same result.

What does *recursive adjoint* mean exactly?

- recursive: the conjugate transpose is applied recursively to all entries of the array (in your case you have array of numbers and transpose of a number is the same number so this does not change anything);
- adjoint: if you would have complex numbers then the operation would return their complex conjugates (in your case you have real numbers so this does not change anything);

Here is an example when both things matter:

```
julia> x = [[im, -im], [1-im 1+im]]
2-element Array{Array{Complex{Int64},N} where N,1}:
 [0+1im, 0-1im]
 [1-1im 1+1im]

julia> permutedims(x)
1×2 Array{Array{Complex{Int64},N} where N,2}:
 [0+1im, 0-1im]  [1-1im 1+1im]

julia> Matrix(x')
1×2 Array{AbstractArray{Complex{Int64},N} where N,2}:
 [0-1im 0+1im]  [1+1im; 1-1im]
```

However, unless you really need to you do not have to do it if you really need to get a conjugate transpose of your data. It is enough to change type assertion to

```
return fx::Array{Float64,2}, fy::AbstractArray{Float64,2}
```

or

```
return fx::Matrix{Float64}, fy::AbstractMatrix{Float64}
```

Conjugate transpose was designed to avoid unnecessary allocation of data and most of the time this will be more efficient for you (especially with large matrices).

Finally the line:

```
return fx::Array{Float64,2}, fy::Array{Float64,2}
```

throws an error also in the Julia command line (not only when run from a script).